# Según IJ los problemas la condicion 'i ==num' y 'for'

Tags: java

problemas la condicion 'i ==num' y 'for'

```
public class Prueba {
    public static boolean esPotencia(int num)
    {
        if(num<1) return false;
        if (num == 2 ) return true;
        int i=2;
        while (true)
        {
            if (i==num) return true;
            if (i>num) return false;
        }    
    }        
    public static int numPares(int[] array) {
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i]%2 == 0)
            {
                if (esPotencia(array[i]))
                {
                    cont++;
                }    
            }    
        }    
        return cont;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a = {1,2,4,8,7,11,0,16};
        System.out.println("Cont = " + numPares(a));
    }   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! NO. todo ese spam significa que tu pregunta no explica nada de nada. Vemos los problemas que te salen. Ahora, que hace el codigo? tenes que explicar que hace el codigo para que entendamos porque te dan los errores.

Comment: Lee tu codigo.. si num == 2 entonces sale de la funcion. En la linea siguiente, i = 2.... por lo tanto num **nunca** es igual a 2, porque si no, salio al principio...

Comment: @gbianchi en efecto tiene razón, pero sabra el motivo de: 'for' loop replaceable with enhanced 'for' :15

Comment: en google esta por todos lados, pero lo que dice es que uses el otro formato de for, que recorre un iterable. No es un error, es un warning, igual que el otro...

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Ejercicio2 {
    public static boolean esPotencia(int num)
    {
        if (num<1) return false;
        if (num == 2) return true;
        int i = 2;
        while (true)
        {
            i = i*2;
            if (i==num) return true;
            if (i>num) return false;
        }
    }
    public static int numPares(int[] array)
    {
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i]%2 == 0)
            {
                if (esPotencia(array[i]))
                {
                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int [] a = {1,2,4,8,7,11,0, 16,12,32};
        System.out.println("(2).Cont = " + numPares(a));
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es solo codigo. Que se supone que es? si es una respuesta, deberias explicar el problema, y explicar como se soluciona....